# Google Cloud IOT- Device Configuration via Firebase/cloud functions?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been able to successfully receive state and telemetry from my iot device using mqtt->pubsub->firebase functions->FCM to an android app. My iot device is also registered to receive the config callback, and it successfully receives the current config mqtt message when the device connects.

Now, I would like to be able to use my android app to initiate a config message to send a run/stop command. I had thought I could accomplish this via an android api call or from within a cloud function. There don't seem to be any examples on the web for this.

This example appears to be intended to run on a 3rd party node.js server rather than from inside a cloud function or an android app: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/manager/manager.js#L865

From within the cloud function it was very easy to use admin.firestore() and admin.messaging() to call functions and accomplish what I needed. However the IOT API's don't appear to work the same way. I'm clearly missing something.

So in short- How can I initiate an IOT config message from android or a cloud function? It would be great if I could access the other registry management functions as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why can't you call the cloud function directly from Android?

Comment: I can probably call the cloud function directly, but i cant figure out how to call the IOT API from within the cloud function. I'm relatively new at this, i probably just cant figure it out. The only API for the IOT core seems to be a REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call a cloud function from the android app and then have that integrate with the IOT api's - you could also have the android client call the rest api's https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/rest/

DeviceManager also has a JAVA interface:

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/device-manager-samples

Comment: Can give me an example of how to call the IOT API from within a cloud functiion?

Comment: I dont know how to, but it looks like it is a standard rest request. I am not that good at javascript/typescript which is what I think cloud functions use. I'm a JAVA person <3

Comment: I'm new to node.js/javascript too.. your bottom link was something I hadn't seen. It shows that there IS a library I can call: com.google.api.services.cloudiot.v1.*  If i can just figure out how to call it from the cloud function I'll be all set.

Comment: Yes - you can skip cloud functions and use the JAVA library to interact with the IOT platform.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api-client

Answer (score 1):

Dazza5000 pointed me to the IOT Core API for Java:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/cloudiot/v1

This will allow me to send config data to my IOT device from Android. I don't think this API can be called from a cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

With [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), all you have to do to make a function you can directly invoke is create an [HTTPS trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  Then, when you have its URL that's shown after deployment, you can invoke that URL using whatever HTTP library is available on the device.  For Android devices, [URLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) is the built-in option.  There should be tons of examples of HTTP triggers (especially in the [functions-samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) repo) and URLConnection code that you can borrow to build this out.

Comment: do you know how to call the IOT core functions from within a cloud function?

Comment: What is an "IOT core function"?

Comment: Specifically in my case i want to send a "run" command to my IOT device. As I understand, the only way to send data "cloud-to-device" is via the updating the device Config. In order to update the device config, i need to call the function com.google.api.services.cloudiot.v1.model.DeviceConfig. This call does not seem to be available from within a cloud function. To be honest, its very restrictive in other ways which make it not really ideal for sending commands, but I think it the only way to send data that direction (TO the device FROM the cloud)

Comment: Cloud Functions code runs on a backend type server, not on a device.